# Should I add /usr/lib/git-core/ to my PATH?

Tags: git, path, gitweb

I was trying to set up `gitweb` on my Mint machine. The man page tells me to run `git-instaweb` in a git repo to get started. That command was not found, but `apt-file` told me that it was in `/usr/lib/git-core/`. So I tried running it with the whole path, but it failed because another command, `git-sh-setup`, was not found:

```
./git-instaweb: 22: .: git-sh-setup: not found
```

This program is also in `/usr/lib/git-core/`.

It would seem that in order to work, this directory must be added to my path. Is that correct? If not, how is it supposed to be set up? The gitweb manpage says nothing about the path.

Comment: When you see "git-pull", what is meant is "git pull". For "git-instaweb", it's "git instaweb".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good sir, perhaps try

```
git instaweb
```

Notice carefully lack of hyphen `-`

Comment: Is there specific reason why the man page says "git-instaweb" then? It seems particularly cumbersome when dealing with things like "git web--browse".

Comment: Git commands used to use the hyphenated format. Perhaps the gitweb documentation hasn't been updated in a while.